# Sending string to wcf service using jquery ajax. why can i only send strings of numbers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-services, wcf

For some reason, I'm only able to pass strings containing numbers to my web service when using jquery ajax. This hasn't been an issue so far because I was always just passing IDs to my wcf service. But I'm trying to do something more complex now but I can't figure it out.

In my interface:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    DataTableOutput GetDataTableOutput(string json);
```

My webservice:

```
public DataTableOutput GetDataTableOutput(string json)
{
    DataTableOutput x = new DataTableOutput();

    x.iTotalDisplayRecords = 9;
    x.iTotalRecords = 50;
    x.sColumns = "1";
    x.sEcho = "1";
    x.aaData = null;



    return x;
}
```

Javascript/Jquery:

```
var x = "1";
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        async: false,
                        url: "Services/Service1.svc/GetDataTableOutput",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        data: x,
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (msg) {
                        },
                        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            //alert(XMLHttpRequest.status);
                            //alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                        }
                    });
```

The above code WORKS perfectly. But when I change x to "t" or even to "{'test':'test'}" I get a Error 400 Bad Request error in Firebug.

Thanks,
John

EDIT: 
Making some progress!
data: JSON.stringify("{'test':'test'}"),
Sends the string to my function!

EDIT2:

```
var jsonAOData = JSON.stringify(aoData);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        async: false,
                        url: sSource,
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        data: "{'Input':" + jsonAOData + "}",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (msg) {
                        },
                        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            //alert(XMLHttpRequest.status);
                            //alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                        }
                    });
```

[image]

EDIT3: I modified the code block I put in EDIT2 up above.

Swapping the " and ' did the trick!

```
$.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        async: false,
                        url: sSource,
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        data: '{"Input":' + jsonAOData + '}',
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (msg) {
                        },
                        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            //alert(XMLHttpRequest.status);
                            //alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                        }
                    });
```

However, I have a new problem:

```
    public DataTableOutput GetDataTableOutput(DataTableInputOverview Input)
    {
```

The input here is completely null. The values I passed from jsonAOData didn't get assigned to the DataTableInputOverview Input variable. :(

Comment: Can you try setting x= '{"test":"test"}'?

Comment: JSON.stringify was my next thought. Can you use your object directly in it, like http://jsfiddle.net/nzNxv/ ?

Comment: no :( same error 400 as before. I found this article which I will read through now. Maybe there's something else I'm doing wrong. http://encosia.com/2009/04/07/using-complex-types-to-make-calling-services-less-complex/

Comment: Hmm... still not working completely. I guess I spoke too soon. I kept working but didn't realize I wasn't actually getting the correct json data in my webservice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the code block I put in EDIT2 up above.

Swapping the " and ' did the trick!

```
$.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        async: false,
                        url: sSource,
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        data: '{"Input":' + jsonAOData + '}',
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (msg) {
                        },
                        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            //alert(XMLHttpRequest.status);
                            //alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                        }
                    });
```

This actually worked but I had to fix the format of the object I was sending to GetDataTableOutputOverview